# Unexpected height

Tags: html, css

I have created header in html/css. Unexpected height is coming in menuOne. How to get rid this height. clear:both also i have added. Anyone please suggest me where i did wrong.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="logo">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/140x60/000/fff" />
</div>
<div class="rightContent">
    <div class="menuOne">
        <div class="fLeft">LeftContent</div>
        <div class="fRight">RightContent</div>
        <div class="cBoth"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="menuTwo">Second menu will come here</div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.fLeft {
    float:left
}
.fRight {
    float:right
}
.cBoth {
    clear:both
}
.logo {
    float:left;
    border:1px solid red
}
.rightContent {
    margin-left:150px;
    border:1px solid blue
}
.menuOne {
    background-color:#ccc
}
.menuTwo {
    background-color:#333;
    color:#fff
}
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fLZHq

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of how you want and what is unexpectedly creating the issue?

Comment: I didnt give any height,padding and margins in menuOne. The menuTwo should fix bottom of menuOne.Extra gray color means some height is coming the height seems equal to image height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing `clear:both` to `clear:right` fixes it.

```
.cBoth {
    clear:right;
}
```

Demo of first approach: http://jsfiddle.net/fLZHq/3/

`clear:both` pushes the element below all the previous floated elements (this includes the logo div in you case). Whereas `clear:right` only pushes it below the right-floated element which you want.

Second approach is to keep the `clear:both` but float your `rightContent` and remove the left margin, like this:

```
.rightContent {
    float:left;
    border:1px solid blue
}
```

Demo of second approach: http://jsfiddle.net/fLZHq/7/

Comment: Why should i give clear:right. clear:both, it clears left and right. how it clear:right works here?

Comment: `clear:both` is pushing `menu2` below the `logo`. Remember that `logo` is also floated left. Whereas `clear:right` pushes `menu2` below `menu1`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.rightContent {
    margin-left:150px;
    float: left;
    border:1px solid blue
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All the issues with css regarding the layout of the page can be found out with the
**3d view**  available in **Firefox**.

You've used float left for image and didn't use float for the rightContent div. So, the image is overlapping your 'rightContent' div. Thats the reason you needed to give margin-left for the 'rightContent' div.

So, once you give float: left for the 'rightContent' div, the unexpected problem will be solved.